# Where can I find explicit descriptions of principal $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$s?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, examples

I am interested in an explicit description of the principal homomorphism from $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ to $G$, for each complex semisimple Lie group $G$. Does any one have specific references please? Kostant's original paper is of course great, and contains a lot, but I do not think it contains explicit descriptions for each specific example (which is what I really want at the moment).

Comment: Malkoun, what do you mean by explicit?  At the level of Lie algebras, do you want more than what is outlined, e.g., in the homework set https://www2.bc.edu/mark-reeder/820hw4.pdf , especially parts f and g there?

Comment: thank you guest. Also interested in the exceptional cases. Anyway, I guess I will work out what they look like using such root formulas. You are right. It is explicit enough.

Comment: guest there is a small inconsistency in the indices in that file in part g). A typo of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try exploring the reference

"Lie Algebras, Geometry, and Toda-Type Systems"

by Alexander V. Razumov, Mikhail V. Saveliev, Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Thank you T. Amdeberhan! Unfortunately, I don't have access to an extensive library right now. And Google only shows some selected pages of that book (which seems indeed to contain what I want). Would you happen to have a reference that is available online (arxiv, or journal say)?

Comment: I'll let you know if I get a full online access.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to the suggested references, one more:

A.L. Onishchik, E.B. Vinberg, Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups,
Springer, 1990. Exercise 4.2.28.

Answer (score 1):

Bourbaki on Lie groups chapters 7-9 has a lot of info. on PRINCIPAL Sl2-triplets
in complex semisimple Lie algebras (and more info in Exercises). 
Is that related to what you need ?

Comment: Thank you Nazih, but I also do not seem to have online access to this book either.

Comment: I will be very glad to lend you the book which belongs to AUB Jafet Library.
What I like about Bourbaki books that most of his exercises are very significant.
Example:  Once, I found an exercise in Bourbaki which implies immediately Brown's Theorem on commuatators of complex semisimple Lie algebras. His idea that every Borel subalgebra  B \subset [a, L]  for some principal nil[potnet elment a of L.; so Brown's Theorem follows by conjugacy pf Borel subalgebras.
 (but Bourbaki did not refer to Brown paper around 1965).

Comment: Thank you Nazih. I am sure it is an excellent reference, and I might borrow it from you at some point. I do recommend that you have a look at Onishchik and Vinberg, "Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups" too: it is full of exercises. You might like it too.

Comment: Ok, I got access to the Bourbaki book(s) on Lie groups, via SpringerLink. They were not showing up initially because I was searching for "Bourbaki Lie groups", instead of spelling the word "groups" the French way, "groupes"!